# Install one Windows (operating system) on 4 Raspberry and with one monitor

Tags: operating-systems, windows

How can I connect four Raspberry Pis together with a switch and install and run only one version of Windows (like Windows 10, 8, 7) on all of them?

How can I show it in one monitor? I mean do I just install part of Windows on each of them? I don't know if it's possible but if you have any ideas, please tell me.

I know how to use Linux for that but I don't know how to do it for Windows. Can you tell me what material I need, i.e. hub, switch, memory card, etc.?

My aim is to get better performance from the Raspberry Pi and create a cluster computer running Windows 7, 8, or 10.

Comment: To what purpose? What are you doing?

Comment: @zich for create module with high performance can directly encode some of coding :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope. This isn't going to happen. You're describing attempting to run an x86 operating system (Windows) on a cluster of ARM devices. Wrong chipset, with CPUs which are too slow, linked together in non-optimal ways - it's just not a viable concept.

Comment: what do i do? @goobering

Comment: There's nothing to be done - you can buy a computer with an x86 CPU and run Windows on it, or you can buy lots of Raspberry Pis, turn them into a cluster and run a suitable ARM operating system on it, but *you cannot run Windows 7, 8 or 10 (the full version of 10, not Win10 IoT) on a cluster of Pis*.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read this thread: 
[Raspberry pi cluster to run Win.10](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=235616)

The first answer states:

> You can run Windows 10 on ARM but that sentence needs to be qualified
>   with a big JUST. See https://www.windowslatest.com/2019/02/1 ...
>   erry-pi-3/ for some details. Legality is in the air at the mo. Windows
>   Insider membership is a requirement (available free for some uses) but
>   folk are running later versions than those released under this
>   agreement.
>
> Windows is still too heavy for 1GB on ARM (I’ve given up on boxes with
>   less than 4GB and 64GB disk) and cannot be spread over multiple Pi
>   boards (or even Intel / AMD). Currently there are a few Pi clusters
>   but a quick search on here will show that they are Linux and great for
>   learning but not cost effective compared to Intel / AMD chips for
>   serious work at small board counts.

The second answer states:

> You don't need to simulate Windows. To run one of the standard versions of Win10 (which appears to be your intent) you need to simulate an Intel or AMD x86 processor on the ARM processors the Pis use. This can be done, but it isn't fast and it isn't particularly susceptible to improvements from parallelism.

To sum up, it's not really worth it.

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible in concept. You need a hypervisor that runs on top of an arm cluster. On top of the hypervisor you can have one or more guest operating systems.

Comment: Hypervisors and virtual machines  do not emulate or translate CPU instructions, the underlying OS needs to support Arm